# stm32f4 CAN RX, i can transmit but can not receive messages

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I'm trying to receive just a message via CAN, but the program end in Error_Handler();

Here the can config:

```
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 10;
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_15TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */
   CAN_FilterTypeDef  sFilterConfig;

   sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
   sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
   sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
   sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
   sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
   sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
   sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

   if(HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
   {
     /* Filter configuration Error */
     Error_Handler();
   }

   HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}
```

Here I posted the function.
It was copied from the stm32 manual. In my hardware setup the CAN transceiver must be enabled setting the relative gpio to high.

```
void StartDefaultTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  /* Infinite loop */
    CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef   TxHeader;
    CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef   RxHeader;

      uint8_t               TxData[8];

      uint32_t              TxMailbox;

        //uint8_t               RxData[8];

  for(;;)
  {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
          TxHeader.StdId = 0x446;
          TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
          TxHeader.DLC = 2;


          TxData[0] = 50;
          TxData[1] = 0xAA;

         // uint32_t freelevel =HAL_CAN_GetTxMailboxesFreeLevel(&hcan1);
/*
          if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &TxHeader, RxData, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
          {
             Error_Handler ();
          }
          */
         //uint32_t messagepending =HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan1,TxMailbox);

        //uint8_t               RxData[8];

         if(HAL_CAN_GetRxFifoFillLevel(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0) != 1)
           {
             // Reception Missing
             Error_Handler();
           }

        if (HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, RxData)!= HAL_OK)
            {
            Error_Handler ();
            }



        /*
        if ((RxHeader.ExtId == 0x105) && (RxHeader.IDE == CAN_ID_STD))
        {

              g_Count1_recv = RxData[3];
              g_Count1_recv = (g_Count1_recv << 8) | RxData[2];
              g_Count1_recv = (g_Count1_recv << 8) | RxData[1];
              g_Count1_recv = (g_Count1_recv << 8) | RxData[0];
          }
        */

    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}
```

The Trasmission of messages works fine, i m just unable to receive with CAN_ERROR_PARAM.
The HAL_CAN_GetRxFifoFillLevel it is different from 1.

[The image shows the RxHeader when the function fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFrsg.png)

Comment: You seem to be expecting there to be a message waiting for you _immediately_. Is this a valid assumption? Or will there be a delay between you sending a message, and receiving one?

Comment: yes, I'm actually trying it with busmaster, transmitting each 10ms the message i expect to see.

Comment: in case of a delay, what function do you suggest to use and have you an example?

Comment: You can use `HAL_Delay(ms)` to delay for a number of milliseconds.

Comment: Now i solved the problem just removing the condition != HAL_OK, but this is not very smart

Comment: I have the same problem. Let me try also removing the condition != HAL_OK.